# Does a return statement close a BufferedReader?

Tags: java, return, bufferedreader

I am trying to understand if the way this code is written actually closes the BufferedReader object.

```
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        if (isContentJson) {
            String enc = getCharacterEncoding();
            if(enc == null) enc = "UTF-8";
            return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream(), enc));
        }
        else {
            return super.getReader();
        }
    }
```

I notice with the above code the BufferedReader object is created in the return statement whereas in the example below the BufferedReader object is guaranteed to be closed.

```
private void processFile(string fName)
{
BufferReader fil = new BufferReader(new FileReader(fName));
String line;
while ((line = fil.ReadLine()) != null)
{
processLine(line);
}
fil.Close();
}
```

Does the first example still close the BufferedReader since the method is terminated after the return statement?

Comment: The first example returns an open bufferedreader. It does not close it.

Comment: @khelwood thank you. I will change the implementation so it is closed.

Comment: Bear in mind that if it returned a closed bufferedreader, that would not be very useful.